# Ruby on Rails - searchkick gem : cluster_block_exception - FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api) - status":403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying to add `elasticsearch` to my Ruby on Rails website using `searchkick gem`. The OS I'm currently using is Ubuntu 16.04 TLS.

I installed elasticsearch 6.2.2 and, so far, the default configurations unchanged.

When I run `curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'` I get :

```
{
    "name" : "viTKcuN",
    "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
    "cluster_uuid" : "aHCpbpvoQd2sieJRWtqI7g",
    "version" : {
        "number" : "6.2.2",
        "build_hash" : "10b1edd",
        "build_date" : "2018-02-16T19:01:30.685723Z",
        "build_snapshot" : false,
        "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
    },
    "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Which, I guess, the desired output.

I then added `gem 'searchkick', '~> 3.0'` to my Gemfile, ran `bundle install` and added `searchkick` to my models.

However, running `Activity.reindex` in terminal results in:

```
Activity.reindex: command not found
```

Running `rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Activity` resulted in the foolowing error:

```
rails searchkick earchkick::ImportError: {"type"=>"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=>"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"} on item with id '1'
```

I tried running `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'`

But then rerunning `rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Activity` again results in the following:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Forbidden: [403] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"},"status":403}
```

I also tried adding `searchkick settings: {blocks: {read_only: false}}` to the Activity model but had the same error when I ran `rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Activity` again.

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fixed it by running `Activity.search_index.delete` in console and then reran `Activity.reindex`

Comment: This certainly works but it's the equivalent of formatting and reinstalling Windows when there's an issue with your OS. @FlimFlam Vir has the correct, surgical approach.

Answer (score 23):

The following worked for me when I got this running rspec tests and the first dB insert setting up the test db env failed with this elastic search error. Fix extracted from [here](https://selleo.com/til/posts/esrgfyxjee-how-to-fix-elasticsearch-forbidden12index-read-only), the key observation:

> By default, **Elasticsearch installed with homebrew on Mac OS goes into read-only mode when you have less than 5% of free disk space.**

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

Comment: the correct command that worked for me is `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": false}'`